# numpy dtype ValueError: invalid shape in fixed-type tuple - how can I get around it?

Tags: python, numpy

I use a custom datatype, e.g. `datatype = np.dtype('({:n},{:n})f4'.format(10000,100000))` to read data from a binary file using

```
np.fromfile(filename, dtype=datatype)
```

However, defining the datatype using np.dtype gives an error for large datasets, as in the example datatype above:

```
ValueError: invalid shape in fixed-type tuple: dtype size in bytes must fit into a C int
```

Initializing an array of that size is no problem: `a=np.zeros((10000,100000))`.
So my question is: Where does that limitation come from and how can I get around it? I can of course use a loop and read chunks at a time, but maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: Why are you using a big `dtype` like this?  I doubt if the developers ever tried something like this.

Comment: They are large matrices, that's the reason for the dtype. I was just surprised that it fits in memory, but the dtype does not allow it.

Comment: `dtype` specifies the nature of elements of an array, not the overall shape of that array.  Why not load the file as a 1d array of `f4`, and reshape it after?

Comment: thanks, that works like also proposed in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a dtype of `'(M, N)f4'` you are effectively specifying the final two dimensions of the output array, e.g.

```
np.zeros(5, np.dtype('(6, 7)f4')).shape
# (5, 6, 7)
```

You could achieve the same outcome by simply reading in the data as a 1D array, then reshaping it to your desired shape:

```
x = np.fromfile(filename, np.float32).reshape(-1, 10000, 100000)
```

Comment: cool, that works! Not sure what the -1 in the reshape is though, I am now using `np.fromfile(filename, np.float32, M*N).reshape(M,N)`

Comment: A `-1` in the `shape` tuple causes numpy to infer the size of that dimension based on the sizes of the other dimensions and the total number of elements in the array